# Join: Two files - but only append last two columns

Tags: files, sed, awk, merge, join

Given the files:

#### 1.txt

```
1, abc, 123, 456, 789
2, lmn, 123, 456, 789
3, pqr, 123, 456, 789
```

#### 2.txt

```
1, abc, 123, 000, 000
3, lmn, 123, 000, 000
9, opq, 123, 000, 000
```

#### OUTPUT.txt

```
ID, NAME, X,    1A,    1B,  2A,   2B   
1, abc, 123, 456, 789, 000, 000
2, lmn, 123, 456, 789, MISSING, MISSING
3, pqr, 123, 456, 789, 000, 000
9, opq, 123, MISSING, MISSING, 000, 000
```

I'ved used [this](http://www.albany.edu/~ig4895/join.htm) for reference.

I tried using the following:

```
join -t , -a1 -a2 -1 1 -2 1 -o 0 -o 1.2 -o 1.3 -o 1.4 -o 1.5 -o 2.4 -o 2.5 -e "MISSING" 1.txt 2.txt
```

Which produces:

```
1, abc, 123, 456, 789, 000, 000
2, lmn, 123, 456, 789,MISSING,MISSING
3, pqr, 123, 456, 789, 000, 000
9,MISSING,MISSING,MISSING,MISSING, 000, 000
```

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with `join` alone. You could do:

```
join -t, -a1 -a2 -o0,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5 -e MISSING 1.txt 2.txt |
  perl -F, -lape '@F[1..2]=@F[5..6] if $F[1] eq "MISSING";
                  $_=join",",@F[0..4],@F[7..8]'
```

- `-p`: use a line by line reading loop like in sed/awk
- `-a`, `-F,`: like awk, split the lines into fields (into the `@F` array).
- `-l`: works on the content of lines (works like `awk` where the input is split on `RS` (`$/`) (but `RS` not included in `$0`) and `ORS` (`$\`) is appended before printing).
- `-e ...`: perl [e]xpression to evaluate for each line.
- Then it reads almost like English: fields 1 to 2 are set to fields 5 to 6 if field 1 (the second field as indexes start at 0) is "MISSING". Then set the content of the current record ($_ is like $0 in awk) to the fields 0 to 4 and 7 to 8.

Actually, writing the same in `awk` is not more complicated:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '$2 == "MISSING"{$2=$6;$3=$7}
                 {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$8,$9}'
```

Answer (score 5):

using just awk:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    BEGIN {m = " MISSING"}

    # process file1
    NR == FNR {lines[$1] = $0; next} 

    # process file2
    {
        added[$1] = $4 OFS $5
        if (!($1 in lines)) {
            $4 = m
            $5 = m
            lines[$1] = $0
        }
    } 

    # print the combined output
    END {
        for (id in lines) {
            if (!(id in added)) 
                added[id] = m OFS m
            print lines[id], added[id]
        }
    }
' 1.txt 2.txt | sort -n
```

```
1, abc, 123, 456, 789, 000, 000
2, lmn, 123, 456, 789, MISSING, MISSING
3, pqr, 123, 456, 789, 000, 000
9, opq, 123, MISSING, MISSING, 000, 000
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to join on first three fields. You should then change the first two delimiters, `join` on the new 1st field and then restore the delimiters:

```
join -t, -j1 -a1 -a2 -o 0 1.2 1.3 2.2 2.3 -e " MISSING" \
<(sed 's/, /\x02/;s/, /\x02/' 1.txt) <(sed 's/, /\x02/;s/, /\x02/' 2.txt) \
| sed 's/\x02/, /g'
```

returns

```
1, abc, 123, 456, 789, 000, 000
2, lmn, 123, 456, 789, MISSING, MISSING
3, pqr, 123, 456, 789, 000, 000
9, opq, 123, MISSING, MISSING, 000, 000
```