# Joining entries based off of column using awk/join

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

I have two files which are pipe-delimited and may have column 1+column2 matches in both, or one file may have the entry while the other does not. Assume my match-key I am going off of equals $1"-"$2 using a pipe '|' as the FS.

file1

```
1111|AAA|foo|50
1111|BBB|foo|30
2222|BBB|foo|10
```

file2

```
1111|AAA|bar|10
1111|CCC|bar|20
3333|AAA|bar|40
```

The desired output would be the following for the first entry (I have this working)

```
1111|AAA|50|10
```

For the second entry file1 (If there is no matching column1+column2 in both files, replace the entry which is missing for foo as 0. And the other way around)

```
1111|BBB|30|0
```

And for an entry key (column1+column2) in file2, but not in file1 (This is entry 3 of file 2 expected output)

```
3333|AAA|0|40
```

So, desired output overall format is listing ALL unique keys which are represented by column1+column2 in BOTH files. With the 3rd column entries being those values from file1 column 4 (or 0 if value doesn't exist in file1) and the 4th column in output as those values in column 4 of file 2 (or 0 if value doesn't exist in file2).

I have done a lot of research and tried many things but I have values not outputting if the column1+column2 pair exists in file2 but not file1 by using the following:

```
join -t"|" -e0 -a1 -a2 -o 1.2,1.3,1.5,2.5 <(<file1 awk -F"|" '{print $1"-"$2"|"$0}' | sort -k1,1) <(<file2 awk -F"|" '{print $1"-"$2"|"$0}' | sort -k1,1)
```

The above case gives me expected output if there is a column1+column2 match in file1 but not file2, and appends a 0 for the match not existing... How can I get this to work for ALL scenarios?

Above command will do some process substitution by adding a key in column 1 in both files which is column1+column2, and then join based off of that new key. -e0 will add a 0 if this key exists in file1 but not file2. How can I get it to cover the case of: New key (column1-column2) exists in file 2 but NOT file 1?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to do this with sqlite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your approach you have to use `join` twice (or [change your approach to do it with a single `join` invocation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/428677/22142)) :

- print the common lines and the unpairable lines from `file1` with `join -t'|' -e0 -a1 -o 1.2,1.3,1.5,2.5 <(<file1 awk -F'|' '{print $1"-"$2"|"$0}' | sort -t'|' -k1,1) <(<file2 awk -F'|' '{print $1"-"$2"|"$0}' | sort -t'|' -k1,1)`
- print the unpairable lines from `file2` with `join -t'|' -e0 -v2 -o 2.2,2.3,1.5,2.5 <(<file1 awk -F'|' '{print $1"-"$2"|"$0}' | sort -t'|' -k1,1) <(<file2 awk -F'|' '{print $1"-"$2"|"$0}' | sort -t'|' -k1,1)`

You can do the same with a single `awk` invocation, storing `$4` in two arrays indexed by e.g. `$1|$2` and then in the `END` block iterating over each array indices, comparing them and printing accordingly:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{z[$1"|"$2]=$4;next}{x[$1"|"$2]=$4}
END{for (j in x){if (!(j in z)){print j, "0", x[j]}};
for (i in z){if (i in x){print i, z[i], x[i]} else {print i, z[i], "0"}}
}' OFS="|"  file1 file2
```

Comment: This looks great! I had attempted using a single awk expression but just could not get it down correctly. I will be verifying this answer tomorrow and update accordingly. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk` approach:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{f1[$1FS$2]=$NF;next} {f2[$1FS$2]=$NF} 
    END{for (x in f1){print x,f1[x],f2[x]?f2[x]:0; delete f2[x]};
        for (y in f2) print y, 0, f2[y]
}' file[12] OFS='|'
```

#### Explanation:

- `NR==FNR{f1[$1FS$2]=$NF;next}`, this will run only for file1 and with the key combination of `$1FS$2` will store last column value `$NF` in array called `f1` (`FS` will substitute with `|` as awk's **F**ield **S**eperator).
- `{f2[$1FS$2]=$NF}`, same as above but this will run only for file2
- `for (x in f1){print x,f1[x],f2[x]?f2[x]:0; delete f2[x]}`, loop within array `f1` and print key (`x`), its value in file1 `f1[x]` and if there same file1 key in file2, then print it as well, else print `0` (Used ternary condition `f2[x]?f2[x]:0`), after that we are also deleting record of same key from file2 with `delete f2[x]`.
- `for (y in f2) print y, 0, f2[y]`, now array `f2` has records which exist in file2 only, so we are printing their key (`y`), `0` because doesn't not exist in file1 and their value in file2 `f2[y]`.

Answer (score 2):

The following replaces the first `|` in both files with `@` (use a character that does not occur elsewhere in the file), performs the `join` and then changes the `@` back to the original `|`.  This way, we create a new `|`-delimited join field consisting of columns 1 and 2 from the original files.

```
join -t'|' -e0 -a1 -a2 -o0,1.3,2.3 \
    <( sed 's/|/@/' file1 | sort )  \
    <( sed 's/|/@/' file2 | sort ) |
tr '@' '|'
```

In the output field specification (`-o`), a zero represents the join field and column 3 in either file is actually column 4 from the original data.

For the given input files, this generates

```
1111|AAA|50|10
1111|BBB|30|0
1111|CCC|0|20
2222|BBB|10|0
3333|AAA|0|40
```

Comment: Yup; with unknown input I usually resort to [low ascii chars](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/220932/22142) which are almost guaranteed to never occur in a text file but that is on gnu setups...